# redistribute modified Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, gpl-compliance

for kids educational purpose, I've made a "modified" version of Raspbian for PC. Pratically speaking, I've simply installed and configured some software (mainly minetest and its python api) and taken a backup from USB key. The backup is a .iso file containing original system partition and custom persistence partition. Now I want to distribute my image (at no cost) so kids at home can write it on their usb key and use the learning environment. Since all the pieces are under the (l)gpl license, I'm allowed to freely redistribute it? I have to put the gpl license file somewhere alongside the downloadable image?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ...and provide all of the source code along with any compiled components you've added and/or modified. This doesn't need to be along-side... you can leave a note stating how someone could acquire it (online, mail etc)

Comment: [Distributing free software for money, or not, is encouraged](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.en.html)

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR : You don't have to do anything , since you are not doing commercial business.

If your offer is **explicitly non-commercial**  you can simply point people at raspbian.org / raspberrypi.org and say "just use apt-get source to get the source code for packages". No need to host anything yourself , no need to include a written offer for source code. This is the special exception in paragraph 3c) of the GPLv2.

Please note that the proprietary software in official Raspbian images like Mathematica and Oracle JVM is most likely not redistributable. Remove it before creating your own images.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately the procedure to get all components working together as I want is fairly complex and the main reason behind the entire work is to ease the environment setup for students, therefore your solution isn't an option for me (but I'll bear it in mind for future)

Comment: You misunderstand. As long you don't make money with GPLv2 binaries , there is nothing you have to do. If you do make money (which i doubt , since you said its for educational use only) you have to follow the steps  in my sentence  before the last in above answer , no excuses.

Comment: I'm not convinced.  The raspbian image includes licensed version of, say, Java, Minecraft, or Wolfram Alpah which you are not allowed to redistribute.   Also, the GPL doesn't discriminate "commercial" or "money making" offerings.

Comment: The point i was trying to make (probably poorly ..)  is that the Exception granted in paragraph 3c) of the GPLv2 is not available to commerical redistributors.